# Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver Nuget - Asterisk downloading previous version

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nuget, appveyor

I have the package reference set as

```
<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="*" />
```

However tests are failing in AppVeyor throwing this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 100
Current browser version is 99.0.4844.84 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)
```

Shouldn't the asterisk be downloading the latest version on each AppVeyor run?

Comment: Is the asterisk is interpretted as "any version", maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `*-*`. Using `*` only takes into account release versions.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#floating-version-resolutions

Answer (score 0):

Chrome have pushed the version to **100** just now.

[image: Chrome100]

Update your browser (incase not auto updated), you will be good to go.